# How to replace/remove tag in multiple csproj files

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-code, csproj

Is it possible to remove tag from multiple csproj files (e.g. NuGetPackageImportStamp) by using search and replace functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Notepad++ has 'Find in files' functionality to replace in files in the selected location. It is possible to insert filter, use regex...

Sorry for bothering. I didn’t even think to look there.